# Delete file with fineuploader

Tags: fine-uploader

I need to delete a file from AWS s3 servers. For that we written delete method but without handling UUID of the URI hence the issue. We are passing image name through query string.

Is there any way to dnt send id to server or send it as query string.

Any quick reply will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Krishna

Comment: Why aren't you able to parse the UUID in the URI path?

Answer (score 2):

You can't prevent Fine Uploader from sending the UUID in the URI path with the default options.  Honestly, this is how you should be identifying your files server-side, not by file name.  If you would like to pass additional information (parameters) with the delete request, you can do so  via the `setDeleteFileParams` API function.  For example:

```js
var uploader = new qq.FineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: '/my/endpoint'
    },
    deleteFile: {
        enabled: true,
        endpoint: '/my/deletefile/endpoint'
    },
    callbacks: {
        onDelete: function(id) {
            this.setDeleteFileParams({filename: this.getName(id)}, id);
        }
    }
});
```

The above code will include a "filename" parameter in the querystring with the name of the file as a value.  Also as of version 3.7 (just released yesterday) you can specify a new `method` property on the `deleteFile` option with a value of "POST" if you want to send delete file requests using POST instead of DELETE.  In that case, all parameters, including the UUID, will be sent as URL encoded parameters in the request body.  See the [blog post on support for delete files via POST](http://blog.fineuploader.com/2013/06/05/delete-files-via-post-and-delete-requests/) for more details

Comment: no parameter send via `onDelete`, you must use `setDeleteFileParams` on `onSubmitDelete`

Comment: hi @Mostafa can you share me how you did that